# Java error: Cannot find symbol [method .addJob] and [method .searchR]

Tags: swing, linked-list

In my driver program, it gives me cannot find symbol error :

"java:201: error: cannot find symbol report.setText(list1.searchR(in)) ;"

"java:257: error: cannot find symbol list5.addJob(n2.getText(),""+(rand5++) ,t,0);"

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MenuDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    indList list1= new indList();
    indList list3= new indList();
    indList list4= new indList();
    indList list5= new indList();
    indList list6= new indList();

    public static int rand=1000;
    public static int rand2=1000;
    public static int rand3=1000;
    public static int rand4=1000;
    public static int rand5=1000;
    String ty[] = {"SAB", "Aramco","Sabic","JANA","alMuhaidib"};
    JComboBox acty1 =new JComboBox(ty);

    JMenu me=new JMenu("Employer");
    JMenuItem mep= new JMenuItem("Post Needed Jobs");
    JMenuItem mex=new JMenuItem("Exit");

    JMenu ms=new JMenu("Job Seeker");
    JMenuItem msf= new JMenuItem("Find Available Jobs");
    JMenuItem msa= new JMenuItem("Assign to a New Job");

    JMenuBar bar=new JMenuBar();


    //// post jobs

    JLabel l1=new JLabel ("Your organization name:", JLabel.CENTER);

    JLabel l2=new JLabel ("The job title needed is:", JLabel.CENTER);
    JTextField n2 =new JTextField(50);

    JButton b1=new JButton("Submit");
    JButton b2=new JButton("Cancel");

    JPanel empp1=new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));


    //////////// Assign 

    JLabel lll4=new JLabel("The job title that you want to request for:", JLabel.CENTER);
    JTextField nnn3=new JTextField(50);

    JLabel lll5=new JLabel("Your name:", JLabel.CENTER);
    JTextField nnn4=new JTextField(30);

    JLabel lll6=new JLabel("ID:", JLabel.CENTER);
    JTextField nnn5=new JTextField(10);

    JLabel lll7=new JLabel("Phone number:", JLabel.CENTER);
    JTextField nnn6=new JTextField(10);

    JLabel lll8=new JLabel("Email address:", JLabel.CENTER);
    JTextField nnn7=new JTextField(50);

    JButton bbb3=new JButton("Send Request");
    JButton bbb4=new JButton("Cancel");

    JPanel sap2=new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,2));

    ////////////// report

    JTextArea report =new JTextArea(15,40); 
    JPanel panel3= new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    Font font = new Font("Times New Romman", Font.BOLD, 30);
```

The MenuDemo class:

```
public MenuDemo(){

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("Job Program");
    setSize(600,600);   
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    empp1.add(l1);
    empp1.add(acty1);
    empp1.add(l2);
    empp1.add(n2);
    empp1.add(b1);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    empp1.add(b2);
    b2.addActionListener(this);

    empp1.setVisible(false);
    add(empp1);


    /////////// result assign 
    sap2.add(lll4);
    sap2.add(nnn3);
    sap2.add(lll5);
    sap2.add(nnn4);
    sap2.add(lll6);
    sap2.add(nnn5);
    sap2.add(lll7);
    sap2.add(nnn6);
    sap2.add(lll8);
    sap2.add(nnn7);
    sap2.add(bbb3);
    bbb3.addActionListener(this);
    sap2.add(bbb4);
    bbb4.addActionListener(this);

    sap2.setVisible(false);
    add(sap2);

    ///////// menu

     me.add(mep);
     me.add(mex);
     mep.addActionListener(this);
     mex.addActionListener(this);
     bar.add(me);

     ms.add(msf);
     ms.add(msa);
     msf.addActionListener(this);
     msa.addActionListener(this);
     bar.add(ms);

     setJMenuBar(bar);

     //////////

        Font fnt = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14);    
        panel3.add(new JLabel ("The Result of search:"));
        JScrollPane scrolpane = new JScrollPane(report);
        report.setFont(fnt);

        scrolpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrolpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        panel3.add(scrolpane);
        panel3.setVisible(false);
        add(panel3);

        setVisible(true);


}



public static void main(String[] args)
{
     MenuDemo jp=new MenuDemo();
}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        report.setText("");
        String c=e.getActionCommand();


        if(c.equals("Post Needed Jobs"))
        {
            empp1.setVisible(true);
            panel3.setVisible(false);
            sap2.setVisible(false);
        }

        else if(c.equals("Exit"))
        {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank You for using Job Program");  
            System.exit(0); 
        }

        else if(c.equals("Find Available Jobs"))
        {

            empp1.setVisible(false);
            panel3.setVisible(true);
            sap2.setVisible(false);

            String in=  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Industry To Search in :[SAB, Aramco,Sabic,JANA,alMuhaidib]");
                if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("SAB"))
                {

                        report.setText("");
```

Line 201:

```
                        report.setText(list1.searchR(in)) ;
                }
                if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("Aramco"))
                {

                        report.setText("");
                        report.setText(list2.searchR(in)) ;
                }
                if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("Sabic"))
                {

                        report.setText("");
                        report.setText(list3.searchR(in)) ;
                }
                if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("JANA"))
                {

                        report.setText("");
                        report.setText(list4.searchR(in)) ;
                }
                if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("alMuhaidib"))
                {

                        report.setText("");
                        report.setText(list5.searchR(in)) ;
                }   

                else

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter correct industry in this list:[SAB, Aramco,Sabic,JANA,alMuhaidib]");
        }

        else if(c.equals("Submit"))
        {
            String t= (String)acty1.getSelectedItem();
            String in=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Industry To Add in :[SAB, Aramco,Sabic,JANA,alMuhaidib]");

            if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("SAB"))
            {
                list1.addJob(n2.getText(),""+(rand++) ,t,0);
                n2.setText("");
            }
            else if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("Aramco"))
            {
                list2.addJob(n2.getText(),""+(rand2++) ,t,0);
            }
            else if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("Sabic"))
            {
                list3.addJob(n2.getText(),""+(rand3++) ,t,0);
            }
            else if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("JANA"))
            {
                list4.addJob(n2.getText(),""+(rand4++) ,t,0);
            }
            else if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("alMuhaidib"))
            {
```

Line 257:

```
                list5.addJob(n2.getText(),""+(rand5++) ,t,0);
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter Correct Industry:[SAB, Aramco,Sabic,JANA,alMuhaidib]");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The IndLisit Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class indList {

    public indNode head, tail;

    public indList(){
        head=tail=null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return head==null;
    }    

    public void addind(String j, String i) 
    {


        if(head==null) 
        {

            head=tail=new indNode(j);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Industry added");   
        } 

        else if (head!=null) 
        {
    //  indNode tmp;

        //  for( tmp=head;tmp!=null && !(tmp.info1.equalsIgnoreCase(i)) ;tmp=tmp.next) ;
        //          if( tmp== null )
                    {
                        tail.next=new indNode(j); 
                        tail=tail.next;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Industry Added");       
                    }
        /*  else

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This job title Have been added Before"); */


    } 
    }



    public String printJob() 
        {
            indNode tmp;
            if(head==null)  
            return " The industry List is Empty ";
            else 
            {
                String r="";
                    for( tmp=head;tmp!=null  ;tmp=tmp.next)     
                    r+="\n============\n The Industry:"+tmp.info2;  
                        return r;
            }

        }

            public boolean searchind(String j) 
    {
        indNode tmp;

            for( tmp=head;tmp!=null && !(tmp.info2.equalsIgnoreCase(j)) ;tmp=tmp.next) ;
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The  Account results: "+ tmp != null);
                if (tmp == null) 
                    return false;
                    else
                    return true;    


    } 


}
```

Comment: your question is unclear ! use simple words and explain step by step how you achieve to the error

Comment: Where is the indList class?

Answer (score 1):

The class indList does not have searchR or addJob methods. This causes the compile errors I think.

```
public void searchR(String input) {
    // do something useful here
}

public void addJob(String input, String id, String selectedItem, int pos) {
    // do something useful here
}
```

I don't know what your code is supposed to do so I cannot provide the implementations of above methods, even if I wanted to.

There are a lot of problems with your code that you could fix to make it more readable and better maintainable:

Use meaningful variable names. Instead of 'n2' give a name that describes the meaning of the field.

Class names start with an uppercase character. Try to avoid abbreviations where not needed. Also avoid referring to the datastructure, so 'Industries' instead of 'indList' and 'IndustryNode' instead of 'indNode'.

Fields that are Object references are automatically initialized to null, so you can replace

```
public indNode head, tail;
public indList(){
    head=tail=null;
}
```

with

```
public IndustryNode head;
public IndustryNode tail;
```

There many more improvements possible but this is a start.